# Cannot round correctly a MATLAB fixed point number to the Nth decimal place

Tags: matlab, simulink, fixed-point

For the purposes of my application the result of a fixed point calculation needs to be rounded to the 2nd decimal place first and then rounded to integer. So, if you consider a number like `0.4962` after you round it to 2 decimal places you get `0.5`. And once you round that to integer you get `1`.
Problem is some values are not getting rounded correctly.

Since MATLAB's round function does not support Nth decimal place rounding for arguments of type `fi` I'm using the following algo:

1. Multiply the number with 10 ^ (desired decimal place)
2. Round result to integer using the `Round` rounding method
3. Divide result by 10 ^ (desired decimal place)

Let's consider this code:

```matlab
format long g
a = fi(33.495, 0, 64, 40)
b = fi(0, 0, 64, 40)
math = fimath('RoundingMethod', 'Round', 'ProductMode', 'SpecifyPrecision', 'ProductWordLength', 64, 'ProductFractionLength', 40)
b(:) = round(math.mpy(a, fi(100, 0, 8, 0)))
b(:) = divide(numerictype(0, 64, 40), b, 100)
```

Unfortunately the output of this isn't `33.5` as expected, but `33.49` Here's the complete output:

```
          33.4949999999999

          DataTypeMode: Fixed-point: binary point scaling
            Signedness: Unsigned
            WordLength: 64
        FractionLength: 40
b = 
     0

          DataTypeMode: Fixed-point: binary point scaling
            Signedness: Unsigned
            WordLength: 64
        FractionLength: 40
math = 
        RoundingMethod: Round
        OverflowAction: Saturate
           ProductMode: SpecifyPrecision
     ProductWordLength: 64
 ProductFractionLength: 40
               SumMode: FullPrecision
b = 
        3349

          DataTypeMode: Fixed-point: binary point scaling
            Signedness: Unsigned
            WordLength: 64
        FractionLength: 40
b = 
          33.4899999999998

          DataTypeMode: Fixed-point: binary point scaling
            Signedness: Unsigned
            WordLength: 64
        FractionLength: 40
```

What do I do?

Comment: So you want to round 0.495 and up to 1.0, and lower values to 0.0. Just implement that directly, examining the fractional part of the number. This sounds stupid to me, but if that is what you want, it’s not hard to do.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear to those trying to help (I missed it the first time myself), performing the fixed-point calculations that the OP describes requires having installed the Fixed-Point Designer Simulink product.

Answer (score -1):

Matlab supports rounding a number upto a specified number of decimal points.

```
var = 0.4962
var = round(var,2) # (gives you 0.50)
var = round(var) # (gives you 1.0)
```

Comment: Your example uses a double literal (floating point number). My question is about fixed point numbers. For such numbers `round` does not support Nth decimal place rounding:
```>> round(fi(0.123, 0, 64, 60), 2)
Error using embedded.fi/round
Too many input arguments.```